# Embedding video to pdf?

Tags: pdf, embedded-resource

Hello i have embedded video to pdfs using purepdf library, the problem is the pdf reader ask for decoder when its going to play video, the video plays successfully on systems where decoders are installed, but cannot play on system where decoders are not installed, is there any way to embed the decoders in pdf

help required.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but I'd suggest simply creating a simple website instead of using a PDF, as far as I know you cannot embed video codecs or decoders in a webpage. From my experience they require running an installer each time. Also, keep in mind, search engines don't parse PDF files as highly as they do webpage. (if they read the content at all- they didn't last i checked). if SEO is a priority for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot embed decoders in the PDF file. Only the movie can be embedded.